# MySQL query seems to be ignoring part of WHERE statement within stored function

Tags: mysql, function, field, where-clause

I am having quite a frustrating problem with a stored function in MySQL. 
I have a database full of session data from users connecting to a wireless hotspot.  I am trying to select individual user download statistics from within a selected month.  My problem is that the subquery within the function seems to ignore the `mac` field in the WHERE statement. Here is my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_month_download(mo varchar(45), box int(11), mac varchar(45))   RETURNS DOUBLE
BEGIN
    DECLARE dwnld double;
    IF mo IS NULL THEN
        SET mo := CONCAT(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', MONTH(NOW())),'-','01');
    END IF;
    SET dwnld := (
        SELECT SUM(`tx_bytes`) 
        FROM `session` 
        WHERE `assoc_time` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mo) 
        AND `disassoc_time` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(mo, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
        AND `mac` = mac
        AND `controller_id` = box
    );
    return dwnld;
END
```

Running this:

```
SELECT get_month_download('2012-09-01', '2', '00:21:5c:56:be:a3');
```

Returns download data for the entire table, though it is using the `controller_id` to filter the data.

If I run the subquery outside of the function using the same parameters, it works fine.  What gives?

To be more clear, running this query:

```
SELECT SUM(`tx_bytes`) 
FROM `session` 
WHERE `assoc_time` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-09-01') 
AND `disassoc_time` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD('2012-09-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
AND `mac` = '00:21:5c:56:be:a3'
AND `controller_id` = '2';
```

returns the correct download statistic for that user.  Where the function returns the statistic for all users of that controller.

Comment: What is the extra parathesis after box in  `AND controller_id = box);` ?

Comment: @Ray: It matches the opening parenthesis in `SET dwnld := (SELECT SUM(tx_bytes)`.  The value of `dwnld` is being set to the result of a subquery.  It confused me at first too :)

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Can you provide a sample table schema and data use [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Here it is in SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f703/1.  I did delete a constraint, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: If I place null in the parameter for the mac field, it returns null.  If I place any other value into the mac parameter, it returns the download statistic for all users within that controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should really reflect back to what my teachers taught me in college more often.  The issue was that the variable `mac`, in the scope of the select statement, was seen as a field from the table, and not as my parameter from the function.  So, changing the parameter name fixed the issue:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_month_download(mo varchar(45), box int(11), inmac varchar(60)) RETURNS DOUBLE 
BEGIN  
    DECLARE dwnld double;
    IF mo IS NULL THEN
        SET mo := CONCAT(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-', MONTH(NOW())),'-','01');
    END IF;
    SET dwnld := (
        SELECT SUM(`tx_bytes`)   
        FROM `session`    
        WHERE `assoc_time` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mo)    
        AND `disassoc_time` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(mo, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))      
        AND `controller_id` = box
        AND `mac` = inmac
    );
     return dwnld; 
END
```

This has been a 'smack in the face' moment.  Thank you all for your help.

Comment: :) I'm glad I learned this from your query rather than from my experience!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there is more than one `controller_id` present?

```
SELECT DISTINCT controller_id FROM session
```

How many records does this query fetch you?

If this fetches you only one record, and that corresponds to box = 2, there is no issue.

If there are multiple controller ids, run this query,

```
SELECT COUNT(1), controller_id 
FROM session 
WHERE assoc_time > '2012-01-01' 
AND disassoc_time < '2012-01-31'
AND mac = '00:21:5c:56:be:a3'
GROUP BY controller_id
```

How many rows does this return? If it returns just one record for controller_id 2, there isn't any isssue.

Comment: There are 4 `controller_id`s.  I have confirmed that it is correctly selecting rows with `controller_id` as 2.

Comment: Added a second query to check if anything is filtered out by the other clauses

Comment: I needed to add `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` to both of the dates in order for it to return anything because the time is stored in `int` fields rather than datetime -- data transferred over from a different database.  It did indeed return a record with a count of 268.

Comment: I agree there should be no issue.  However, when putting this query into a function and using IN parameters for the values within the WHERE statement, it fails to filter using the `mac` field.